# lastwaittype frequently beocmes SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD in SQL server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008

We have an SQL server 2008 Express R2 with about 10 databases of size about 500MB each. For one of our database RB, one or more sessions have lastwaittype as **SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD**.

When we execute the following query, the result is **"SQL Server 10.50.1600.1 - RTM (Express Edition with Advanced )"**

```
SELECT 'SQL Server ' 
+ CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') AS VARCHAR) + ' - ' 
+ CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('productlevel') AS VARCHAR) + ' (' 
+ CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('edition') AS VARCHAR) + ')'
```

When we searched on the net for this issue, most articles say "We are in good shape as long as "runnable_tasks_count" is zero and that is the case for us. But when we see one or more sessions of our RB Database having lastwaittype as **SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD**, we are no longer able to execute queries in RB. Our web application using RB DB is not working due to this. Any help is appreciated.